# Fullcalendar, preventing user from selecting multiple day event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

In my fullcalendar http://fullcalendar.io/
I want to prevent a user to be able to create an event on multiple days

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView:  'agendaWeek',
    lang:         "fr",
    header:       false,
    timezone:     'local',
    minTime:      "08:00:00",
    columnFormat: 'dddd',
    selectHelper: true,
    selectable:   true,
    select: function(start, end, id, allDay) {
      var eventData = {
        start: start,
        end: end,
        id: 1,
        block:  true,
        editable: true,
        backgroundColor: "#469278"
      };

      // console.log(moment(eventData.start["_d"]).format("dddd"));
      // console.log(moment(eventData.end["_d"]).format("dddd"));


      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true

      // console.log(eventData);
      if (moment(eventData.start["_d"]).format("dddd") != moment(eventData.end["_d"]).format("dddd")) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
      };
      var day         = moment(eventData.start["_d"]).format("dddd");
      var start_time  = moment(eventData.start["_d"]).format("HH:mm");
      var end_time    = moment(eventData.end["_d"]).format("HH:mm");
      var id          = moment(eventData.end["_id"]);

      var slot        = {
        day: day,
        start_time: start_time,
        end_time: end_time
      };
      array_dispo.push(slot);

      $("#dispo_array").val(JSON.stringify(array_dispo));
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
  });
});
```

When a user is selecting a start date that is different from the end date of his event I thus tried to use the unselect method from the doc http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/unselect_method/ like this :

```
  if (moment(eventData.start["_d"]).format("dddd") != moment(eventData.end["_d"]).format("dddd")) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
          };
```

But unfortunately this code doesnt automatically deselects the current selection...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do a check in your `select` method and then decide whether you want to `render` the event or not.

I also use `Moment.js` to calculate dates and durations, this library is included with FullCalendar (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/)

So I played around and came up with this:

```
select: function (start, end) {
    var mEnd = $.fullCalendar.moment(end);
    var mStart = $.fullCalendar.moment(start);

    if (mEnd.isAfter(mStart, 'day')) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    } else {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
            start: mStart,
            end: mEnd,
            allDay: false
        },
        true // stick the event
        );
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    }
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle if you want to see it in action: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/slyvain/j4b6hnm5/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using this way:

```js
eventResize: function(eventResizeInfo) {
  console.log('eventResize is called');
  var event = eventResizeInfo.event;
  if (event.start.getDay() !== event.end.getDay()) {
    eventResizeInfo.revert();
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent users from selecting multiple days at a time

```
selectAllow: function(selectedEvent) {
      let startDate = selectedEvent.start;
      let endDate = selectedEvent.end;
      endDate.setSeconds(endDate.getSeconds() - 1);
      if (startDate.getDate() === endDate.getDate()) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

Simply add the following option to your calendar:

```
selectAllow: (selectInfo) => { return selectInfo.start.getDay() === selectInfo.end.getDay() },
```